# Is it possible to read/write to a USB device on OS X without writing a device driver in C++?

Tags: macos, go, usb, driver, hid

I'm interested in writing an HID USB Device Driver for OS X entirely in Golang, but I can't find any recent documentation that hasn't been marked as deprecated. On Linux, I'm familiar with writing to usb devices in `/dev/`, but I don't see similar special files show up in that directory in OS X (10.13.6 at the time this was written). The only documentation I've found is for IOKit, which seems like it requires writing the driver in C++, or using an existing c-lib and compiling my dependent golang app with cgo. I wanted to avoid this step as a thought-experiment, but I'm not sure if this is possible at this point. Can anyone confirm or deny if this is possible, and if it is possible, point me in the right direction?

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you run `diskutil list` you will see the device special files you couldn't see.

Comment: On Ubuntu, when a USB device is inserted, there's a new file added to `/dev/usb/`. However, there is no equivalent on OS X. `diskutil list` shows storage devices, but I'm not trying to interact with a storage device, I'm trying to interact with an HID USB device (luxafor, to be specific).

Comment: Sorry, I see. I missed the HID aspect of your question - which was clearly there all along for all to see :-)